# UNIX Command to sort file based on word delimited

Tags: command-line, unix, sorting

I have a file that has lines `file.txt` like this:

> www.site.com/230207|Sophie Rundle **title:** Episodes|5irko3ke 
>   www.site.com/228264|Camilla Luddington **title:** Balifornication|5423234 
>   www.site.com/228592|Sarah Power **title:** Californication|23423423 
>   www.site.com/229022|Ali Cobrin **title:** American Reunion|tgkmktgkmtg 
>   www.site.com/190074|Eva Green **title:** The Dreamers|rfrrfrf

I want it to be sorted into `fileSorted.txt` alphabetically by the word that comes after "title", so the result would be:

> www.site.com/229022|Ali Cobrin **title:** American Reunion|tgkmktgkmtg 
>   www.site.com/228592|Sarah Power **title:** Balifornication|23423423 
>   www.site.com/228264|Camilla Luddington **title:** Californication|5423234 
>   www.site.com/230207|Sophie Rundle **title:** Episodes|5irko3ke 
>   www.site.com/190074|Eva Green **title:** The Dreamers|rfrrfrf

I know that we have to use the `sort` command, so I tried:

```
sort --field-separator='title:'  --key=1  file.txt > fileSorted.txt
```

but I got this result:

```
sort: multi-character tab ‘title:’
```

I tried to search around the internet but I couldn't' find a solution. How can I sort the file the way I want to as explained above? The file has 100K lines so performance matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it easily and efficiently using one line in bash:

```
sort --field-separator=':'  --key=3  file.txt > fileSorted.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe too simplistic (it won't work properly if there are fields where the author name has a ":" character in it), but you can simply sort on the ":" field with the command

```
sort -t: -k2 del.file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` to temporarily change the string.  This example makes it a <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/sh
SEP=$(echo x|tr x '\001')
sed -e "s/title:/$SEP/" file.txt | \
sort  -k2 -t "$SEP"  --key=1  |\
sed -e "s/$SEP/title:/" > fileSorted.txt
```

gives

```
www.site.com/229022|Ali Cobrin title: American Reunion|tgkmktgkmtg
www.site.com/228264|Camilla Luddington title: Balifornication|5423234
www.site.com/228592|Sarah Power title: Californication|23423423
www.site.com/230207|Sophie Rundle title: Episodes|5irko3ke
www.site.com/190074|Eva Green title: The Dreamers|rfrrfrf
```

In your example, you were sorting from the beginning of the line.  Based on comments, you intended sorting by the data beginning after the `"title:"` string, requiring the `-k2` option. (I changed the separator option to POSIX, as well).

For reference, POSIX:

- [sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)
- [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)
- [tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this requires --key=2 rather then --key=1 ?

Comment: I had overlooked the -k2 while working on the delimiter (answer is already updated).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what tools you wanted to use, and it's always good to have options, so here's a perl solution to go along with Thomas' sed/sort solution.

```
$ cat file.txt
www.site.com/230207|Sophie Rundle title: Episodes|5irko3ke
www.site.com/228264|Camilla Luddington title: Balifornication|5423234
www.site.com/228592|Sarah Power title: Californication|23423423
www.site.com/229022|Ali Cobrin title: American Reunion|tgkmktgkmtg
www.site.com/190074|Eva Green title: The Dreamers|rfrrfrf
$ cat sortfile.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl --

use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;

while (<>)
{
    push @lines, "$1\x00$_" if /title: (.*)/;
}

foreach (sort @lines)
{
    s/.*\x00//;

    print $_;
}
$ ./sortfile.pl file.txt
www.site.com/229022|Ali Cobrin title: American Reunion|tgkmktgkmtg
www.site.com/228264|Camilla Luddington title: Balifornication|5423234
www.site.com/228592|Sarah Power title: Californication|23423423
www.site.com/230207|Sophie Rundle title: Episodes|5irko3ke
www.site.com/190074|Eva Green title: The Dreamers|rfrrfrf
```

The concept is to copy the text you want to sort on to the front, sort, and remove the copied text. The key parts are:

```
while (<>)
{
    push @lines, "$1\x00$_" if /title: (.*)/;
}
```

This loops over all the lines in any files named on the command line (or standard input if there aren't any) and reads each line into `$_`. The `if` on the end of the 3rd line both makes sure the line looks like one we want to process, and saves everything after `title:` in `$1`. The `push` then pushes a line onto `@lines` which contains the title (from `$1`), a separator that shouldn't occur in a title (ASCII `nul`), and the rest of the line. When this loop is done, all the lines are in `@lines` with the title copied to the front.

```
foreach (sort @lines)
{
    s/.*\x00//;

    print $_;
}
```

This loops over all the lines accumulated in `@lines` after sorting them. Because the title's been copied to the beginning of each line, the lines are sorted by title. The `s/.*\x00//;` strips off the title and ASCII `nul` separator, restoring the line to how it was originally. The `print` then prints the entire (restored) line.